# Get gender from first name using API Python

Tags: python, pandas, api, python-requests

I am looking for gender detection based on first name from pandas column.

For example i have array

array(['Walker', 'Daniel', 'Steph', ..., 'Dr. Sylvia', 'Gwendy'],
dtype=object)

I want to create new column in dataframe with gender

| name | gender |
| --- | --- |
| Walker | M |
| Daniel | M |
| Dr. Sylvia | W |
| Gwendy | W |

I used Python API "https://api.genderize.io/?name with code below

```
import requests
import json

name = "Mark"
content = requests.get(f"https://api.genderize.io/?name = {name}").text
gender = json.loads(content)['gender']

print(f"Gender of {name} is {gender}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want something like this (with caching for duplicate names, a shared HTTP session, and proper error handling too):

```
from functools import cache
import pandas as pd
import requests

# Use a single session for performance
sess = requests.Session()


@cache
def get_gender(name: str) -> str:
    resp = sess.get(f"https://api.genderize.io/", params={"name": name})
    resp.raise_for_status()
    return resp.json()["gender"]


def get_gender_or_none(name: str) -> str | None:
    try:
        return get_gender(name)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"Failed to get gender for {name}: {exc}")
        return None


df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Walker", "Daniel", "Steph", ..., "Dr. Sylvia", "Gwendy"]})
df["gender"] = df["name"].apply(get_gender_or_none)
```